# Segmentation fault while trying to implement fixed size queue in C++

Tags: c++, stl, segmentation-fault, queue

I wanted to implement a fixed size queue, I could have easily done with a struct having a queue as one of the data members and a member function that takes care of the push part of the queue, but rather wanted to try it out by inheriting queue like this.

```
template<typename T>
struct f_queue : public queue<T>{
    int n;
    T prev;

    f_queue(int n_):
        n(n_){}

    void push(T data){
        if(this->size() < this->n){
            this->push(data);
        }else{
            prev = this->front();
            this->pop();
            this->push(data);
        }
    }
};
```

This compiles just fine but for some reason it gives a segmentation fault and the gdb says

> Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
> 0x0000555555555862 in std::_Deque_iterator<int, int&,
> int*>::_S_buffer_size() ()

Not really sure what that is supposed to mean? When tried doing a **backtrace** the output comes out to be

```
#9913 0x0000555555554ec6 in f_queue<int>::push(int) ()
#9914 0x0000555555554ec6 in f_queue<int>::push(int) ()
#9915 0x0000555555554ec6 in f_queue<int>::push(int) ()
#9916 0x0000555555554ec6 in f_queue<int>::push(int) ()
#9917 0x0000555555554ec6 in f_queue<int>::push(int) ()
#9918 0x0000555555554ec6 in f_queue<int>::push(int) ()
#9919 0x0000555555554ec6 in f_queue<int>::push(int) ()
```

doesn't stop goes infinitely. Need help with this.Thanks in advance.

Comment: You introduced a recursion (probably unintended) with `this->push(data);`. I assume, you actually want `queue<T>::push(data);` to refer to `push()` of base class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your push function always recurses into itself:

```cpp
void push(T data){
        if(this->size() < this->n){
            this->push(data);//HERE f_queue::push is called
        }else{
            prev = this->front();
            this->pop();
            this->push(data);//HERE f_queue::push is called
        }
    }
```

You probably meant to call the base class's push:

```cpp
void push(T data){
        if(this->size() < this->n){
            queue<T>::push(data);
        }else{
            prev = this->front();
            this->pop();
            queue<T>::push(data);
        }
    }
```

Note that STL containers are not  meant to be publicly derived from. They do not have virtual destructors, so make sure you never delete through the base class pointer/reference.

#### EDIT

Non-virtual destructor means the  following code is dangerous:

```cpp
std::queue<T>* base = new f_queue<T>();
delete base;//Call std::queue<T>::~queue();
```

There is no way how to force the call of the correct destructor. Making `f_queue`'s destructor virtual will not help. But, as long as you never delete through a pointer to the base class, there is nothing wrong with deriving from any class.

One way to enforce that is to use private inheritance but I'm guessing you are using inheritance in the first place to retain most of the `std::queue`'s API.

Comment: Thanks @Quimby, just a question about destructor, you mentioned that STL containers don't have virtual destructor, so unless I am overriding the destructor for the base class (here queue) , there is no issues with this implementation right?

Comment: @Bad_Panda Expanded my answer. This has almost nothing with to do with override. And to be pedantic, destructors cannot be overriden, deleting a given class always calls all destructors of the base classes.